# New tasks won't delete when checkbox clicked.

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am new to programming and for fun am trying to put together a todo list app.

When the user clicks on the text of the first Item the program will strike-through the text and when the user clicks the checkbox on the first item it disappears like I want it to. But when I add a new task the strike-through and checkbox don't work. Here is my code. Thanks for the.

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "header">
        <h1> To Do List</h1>
    </div>
    <div id = "form">
        <form>
            <input type = "text" id = "todo"> 
            <button type = "button" id= "submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id = "tasklist">
        <ol id = "list">
            <li id = "listitem"><input type = "checkbox" class="checkbox"      
> Clean</li>

        </ol>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my js

```
window.onload = function(){

    //Add new to do task by entering text and clicking submit
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.onclick = function(){
        var task = document.getElementById('todo').value;
        console.log(task);
        var ol = document.getElementById("list")
        var entry = document.createElement('li');
        entry.id = 'id'
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.className = "checkbox"
        entry.appendChild(checkbox)
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
        ol.appendChild(entry);
        };

    //Strike through task if click on text
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    });

    //Remove task when click checkbox
    $(".checkbox").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$("li").click(function(){` click handler will only work for elements that are in the DOM when the handler is applied - it won't work for future elements! You'll need to implement jQuery's `.on()` handler instead, which *will* work for elements that get added to the DOM in the future.

```
//Strike through task if click on text
$(document).on('click','li', function(){
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
});

//Remove task when click checkbox
$(document).on('change','.checkbox', function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3fr54rp0/

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate the event handler for those links since they aren't in the DOM when the page is rendered. You can do this by attaching the `click` handler by using `$(document).on()` and specifying the element you want the handler to attach to.

Here's a reference https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```js
//Add new to do task by entering text and clicking submit
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.onclick = function() {
  var task = document.getElementById('todo').value;
  console.log(task);
  var ol = document.getElementById("list")
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  entry.id = 'id'
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.className = "checkbox"
  entry.appendChild(checkbox)
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
  ol.appendChild(entry);
};

$(document).on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  //Strike through task if click on text
  $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
}).on('click', '.checkbox', function(e) {
  //Remove task when click checkbox
  $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <h1> To Do List</h1>
</div>
<div id="form">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="todo">
    <button type="button" id="submit"> Submit </button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="tasklist">
  <ol id="list">
    <li id="listitem"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> Clean</li>

  </ol>
</div>
```